# Popularity of posts, based on capitalization (no graphs this time)

Tags: discussion, statistics, titles

After [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/popularity-of-questions-based-on-post-time-and-the-most-useless-graph-ever), I became interested in looking for various relationships in post popularity. While reading through the HNQ list, I noticed that some questions are capitalized in title case, and others written like sentences. So, I used a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/edit/1164278) to get a table of question data, and started analyzing.

From a list of 11066 questions, 10937 started with a letter (once `` '"`([{ `` are filtered out). These were divided into six groups, based on the case of the first letters of the words.

**Average Post:**

- Mean Votes: 18.741
- Mean Views: 2444.953

**One Word: Lowercase:**

There are only 8 of these. Statistically, they tend to do worse than average. Note that my program only counted spaces as word boundaries.

- Posts: 0.073%
- Mean Votes: 15.5
- Mean Views: 1767.375

**One Word: Uppercase:**

These tend to do better, although there are only 34 of them.

- Posts: 0.311%
- Mean Votes: 25.971
- Mean Views: 2509.735

**All Lowercase:**

All-lowercase titles tend to score lower, potentially because they tend to be lower-effort questions.

- Posts: 0.91%
- Mean Votes: 7.697
- Mean Views: 1465.273

**Title Case:**

Title case is slightly uglier to me, although the votes seem to indicate that title case questions do better than average.

- Posts: 19.32%
- Mean Votes: 19.359
- Mean Views: 2056.176

**First Word Lowercase:**

There are but 30 questions which don't begin with a capitalized word, but have one later on. They tend to do worse than average.

- Posts: 0.274%
- Mean Votes: 15.567
- Mean Views: 1974.667

**First Word Uppercase:**

This category is all non-title-case posts which begin with a capitalized word (and are more than one word in length). This category gets more average views than title case, but less average votes. Odd.

- Posts: 79.025%
- Mean Votes: 18.708
- Mean Views: 2553.225

---

These results are probably 99% caused by outliers, but still interesting. We can take away some important points from them:

- If you want a post to be popular, capitalizing the first word increases the average number of views by 64%
- Over 98% of question titles are either title case or sentence case
- Only 42 questions are one word in length
- This was not a productive use of my time

Comment: I think you have correlation backwards - questions becoming popular magically changes their titles' capitalization.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit That's also a possibility, although I'd say a question is more likely to be taken seriously if the title is formatted well (and all-lowercase titles tend to be lower quality with more misspellings)

Comment: Now to think of a good challenge where it's appropriate to use all caps in the title so I can be the first!

Comment: @SamDean [Nope!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31552/disarm-the-b-o-m-b)

Comment: @pppery DAMMIT! But that looks like a really interesting challenge, thanks!

Comment: Probably another interesting one is about ending punctuation e.g. `!` or `?`.

Comment: @Bubbler I think I'll do question punctuation and formatting next, then one on answer formatting. Good idea!

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about SEDE, but as a suggestion it might be interesting to plot challenge popularity (votes or views) as a function of challenge length (number of characters)

Comment: @LuisMendo https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18262/the-relationships-between-question-length-views-and-votes-and-more-painfully?noredirect=1&lq=1