# CGCC Data Analysis #1: Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer

A few months ago I posted a few [interesting bits of research](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/popularity-of-questions-based-on-post-time-and-the-most-useless-graph-ever) on data from SEDE. It was fairly well-received, so I figured I'd do some more analysis. I might make this a weekly thing.

I decided to start with tags. This post will show some data relating to the most used tags, the popularity of posts based on the tags they use, and the most common combinations of tags.

All of this data is from April 6, 2020.

### Most used

1. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): 9540 (84.16%)
2. [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string): 1750 (15.44%)
3. [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math): 1362 (12.01%)
4. [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number): 1087 (9.59%)
5. [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art): 1069 (9.43%)
6. [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge): 810 (7.15%)
7. [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence): 680 (6.00%)
8. [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity): 564 (4.98%)
9. [array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation): 530 (4.68%)
10. [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic): 480 (4.23%)
11. [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem): 474 (4.18%)
12. [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest): 395 (3.48%)
13. [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory): 354 (3.12%)
14. [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer): 307 (2.71%)
15. [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output): 303 (2.67%)
16. [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source): 290 (2.56%)
17. [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry): 287 (2.53%)
18. [random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random): 278 (2.45%)
19. [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics): 274 (2.42%)
20. [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes): 272 (2.40%)

### Highest average score

Note: Only contains tags with at least 10 questions

1. [tetris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetris): +83.0 (15647 views)
2. [game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life): +82.9 (16908 views)
3. [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential): +59.9 (8444 views)
4. [new-years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-years): +50.0 (13467 views)
5. [color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color): +49.1 (10966 views)
6. [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata): +48.9 (7895 views)
7. [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling): +48.0 (53586 views)
8. [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded): +44.3 (11880 views)
9. [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining): +41.5 (7826 views)
10. [error-message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-message): +39.9 (11323 views)
11. [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world): +39.8 (10270 views)
12. [stateful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stateful): +38.7 (9483 views)
13. [busy-beaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/busy-beaver): +36.3 (6072 views)
14. [obfuscation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obfuscation): +31.8 (7838 views)
15. [factorial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial): +31.5 (5103 views)
16. [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design): +31.2 (1907 views)
17. [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest): +31.0 (8131 views)
18. [radiation-hardening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening): +30.7 (2908 views)
19. [interactive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive): +29.9 (4293 views)
20. [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill): +29.8 (3398 views)

### Most common combinations

1. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string): 1658
2. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math): 1214
3. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art): 1024
4. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number): 1008
5. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence): 625
6. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity): 527
7. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[array-manipulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array-manipulation): 508
8. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem): 457
9. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic): 447
10. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory): 328
11. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer): 288
12. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry): 262
13. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[random](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random): 254
14. [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number): 248
15. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips): 243
16. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes): 232
17. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date): 229
18. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output): 227
19. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics): 224
20. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid): 220

### Most common combinations (compared to individual usage)

Note: Only contains tags with at least 10 questions

1. [fewest-operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fewest-operations)[golf-cpu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golf-cpu): 5 (33.33%, 100.00%)
2. [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)[game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life): 12 (30.77%, 46.15%)
3. [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)[stack-exchange-api](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-api): 19 (25.00%, 57.58%)
4. [assembly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly)[machine-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-code): 5 (23.81%, 62.50%)
5. [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)[c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): 13 (24.53%, 39.39%)
6. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string): 1658 (17.38%, 94.74%)
7. [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle)[c#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23): 9 (22.50%, 37.50%)
8. [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming)[haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell): 5 (21.74%, 33.33%)
9. [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)[java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java): 24 (16.44%, 54.55%)
10. [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)[linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra): 30 (15.15%, 73.17%)
11. [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)[image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing): 50 (16.50%, 40.65%)
12. [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes): 73 (20.62%, 26.84%)
13. [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)[logic-gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-gates): 11 (16.92%, 36.67%)
14. [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence): 202 (18.58%, 29.71%)
15. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math): 1214 (12.73%, 89.13%)
16. [error-correction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-correction)[coding-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-theory): 2 (18.18%, 28.57%)
17. [rubiks-cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)[cubically](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubically): 3 (12.50%, 75.00%)
18. [binary-tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-tree)[tree-traversal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree-traversal): 4 (19.05%, 23.53%)
19. [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)[python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python): 39 (14.39%, 37.14%)
20. [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)[underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded): 46 (11.65%, 92.00%)

### Interesting Takeaways

- Code golf makes up over 84% of the challenges on this site
- Despite now being strongly discouraged, [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded), and [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) have a surprisingly high average score
- 92% of all underhanded challenges were popularity contests
- A few popular questions, such as [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life), heavily influence the average score of some tags like [tetris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetris)
- Of all the top 20 most often combined tags, [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) and [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) are the only ones to not include [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
- Just 11 out of 277 tags have not been used in combination with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Which 11 haven't been used in combination with [tag:code-golf]? I'm going to post challenges with these tags.

Comment: I don't think that popularity contests have been officially banned, they have just fallen heavily out of favor.

Comment: @petStorm [tag:king-of-the-hill], [tag:atomic-code-golf], [tag:code-trolling], [tag:golf-cpu], [tag:proof-golf], [tag:code-shuffleboard], [tag:challenge-writing], [tag:showcase], [tag:prelude], [tag:ast-golf], and [tag:box-256]

Comment: I find the [math] [number] tag combination a bit worrying...

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I should post a question with the tags [tag:math] [tag:number] [tag:integer] [tag:arithmetic] [tag:number-theory]

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I've [paired](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203464/sum-in-2540-sums) [tag:code-golf] with [tag:code-shuffleboard]. So, 10 tags left?

Comment: @petStorm I suppose so. It might be a bit hard to pair some of the remaining ones, like [tag:code-golf] and [tag:code-trolling].

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms It should be quite easy to make a tips for golfing in Prelude.

Comment: So, what do you do? Change the part that says `Just 11 out of 277 tags`?

Comment: @petStorm I think just keep everything the same (as I'd probably have to update everything else, too, to keep it accurate), and maybe completely update it once a month or something like that.

Comment: Could you post a link to the Meta post about popularity contests no longer being allowed? I had a great question in mind for that tag.

Comment: @ouflak It seems [tag:popularity-contest]s are still allowed, just not recommended.

Comment: @ouflak If it is also tagged [tag:code-golf], awesome!